# Linux Traffic Control (tc) - Enforces Only Average Bandwidth Usage or Also Prevents Spikes

Tags: linux, tc

I would like to "level off" bandwidth spikes coming out of Kubernetes pod. Setting Linux tc to 10MB enforces average usage of 10MB or also prevent spikes of over 10MB? Is tc the way to control bandwidth spikes coming out of Kubernetes Pod?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: We have seen cases where bandwidth usage spike even for 1 minutes caused other modules to lose health-checks etc. I prefer the spike to be spread over few minutes so it will not block critical traffic even for just one minute.

Comment: It's often implemented using [token buckets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket). Reading how it's working can help understand how average and spikes are handled.